# Traverse a list of tuples containg a string and list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, traversal

I have a list of tuples which contains a string and another list. It is as follows:

```
board = [('10S', []), ('3H', []), ('6C', ['KS', '9C']), ('6H', []), ('7D', []), ('9S', ['AS', 'KS'])]
```

I want to traverse such that comparison is done as follows:

```
10S 3H
3H 6C
6C KS
6C 9C
6C 6H
6H 7D
```

and so on...

That is the `get_mapping()` written below will call the values for `prev2` and `prev1`.

I have implemented the following code:

```
for val in board:
    print "Val is: " + str(val)
    if cnt == 0:
        prev2 = val[0][0]
        prev1 = val[1][0]
        cnt += 1
        get_mapping(prev2,prev1,True)
    else:
        prev2 = prev1
        if len(val[1]) > 0:
            for v in val[1]:
                prev1 = v
                cnt += 1
                get_mapping(prev2,prev1,False)
        else:
            prev1 = val[0]
            cnt += 1
            get_mapping(prev2,prev1,True)
```

I know the first condition is wrong. I am stuck a little as to how to traverse to get above comparison. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a generator yielding pairs:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

master_board_state = [('10S', []), ('3H', []), ('6C', ['KS', '9C']),
                      ('6H', []), ('7D', []), ('9S', ['AS', 'KS'])]

def pairs(state):
    for (key, lst), nxt in zip_longest(state, state[1:]):
        yield from ((key, x) for x in lst)
        if nxt is not None:
            yield key, nxt[0]

print('\n'.join(str(p) for p in pairs(master_board_state)))
```

Output:

```
('10S', '3H')
('3H', '6C')
('6C', 'KS')
('6C', '9C')
('6C', '6H')
('6H', '7D')
('7D', '9S')
('9S', 'AS')
('9S', 'KS')
```

In above [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) will yield items from `state` as pairs. Since first parameter is longer than second one on last iteration `None` is used as fillvalue. Then the loop will first `yield from` generator that returns `(key, list item)` tuples and finally yields current and next key.

**Update** For Python 2 minor modifications are required since it doesn't have `yield from` and `zip_longest` is known as [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

master_board_state = [('10S', []), ('3H', []), ('6C', ['KS', '9C']),
                      ('6H', []), ('7D', []), ('9S', ['AS', 'KS'])]

def pairs(state):
    for (key, lst), nxt in izip_longest(state, state[1:]):
        for x in lst:
            yield key, x
        if nxt is not None:
            yield key, nxt[0]

print '\n'.join(str(p) for p in pairs(master_board_state))
```

Comment: I am getting an error at this line "yield from ((key, x) for x in lst)" telling me it is an invalid syntax.

Comment: @hshantanu You're probably using Python 2 which doesn't have `yield from` or `zip_longest`. See the updated answer for Python 2 version.

Answer (score 3):

So this is very specific kind of traversal, which can be done through a generator.

Update: initially tried with a complex generator expression but missed the tail so had to end up with a generator function similar to @niemmi but with a slightly different approach.

```
from itertools import tee

# from itertools recipes
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def pairs(d):
    for (a, x), (b, y) in pairwise(d):
        yield from ((a, n) for n in x)
        yield a, b
    yield from ((b, n) for n in y)

>>> list(pairs(board))
[('10S', '3H'),
 ('3H', '6C'),
 ('6C', 'KS'),
 ('6C', '9C'),
 ('6C', '6H'),
 ('6H', '7D'),
 ('7D', '9S'),
 ('9S', 'AS'),
 ('9S', 'KS')]
```

Comment: Nice answer, though it will need some minor modifications for Python 2. As 'yield from' won't work in Python 2.

Comment: Indeed, turn the `yield from ...` into `for i in ...: yield i`.